# android layout fixing

Tags: android, image, layout

How do i create exactly same list row layout as image below
[image]

I tried with below code but gap between two rows are much more bigger than expected

```
    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btndel"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_new"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="360dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/cover" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/drag_72" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: First, you can control the gap between rows using attributes of the row (e.g. height, padding, margins, etc.).  Yet, if you're after such a layout, I would recommend using a ListView with an adapter instead of TableLayout.

Comment: No attribute are working and ofcourse i am using listView layout and its a ListView Custom row....

Comment: Then why are you using TableRow as a layout?  TableRow is supposed to be used inside a TableLayout.  For your purposes, use FrameLayout or LinearLayout as a list row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TableRow>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/btndel"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/delete_new"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/cover" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/drag_72" />
</TableRow>
```

I changed only `layout_height` property of the button, because maybe the size of the image is less than `360dp` which you have set currently.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the following layout for your custom list items:
 **custom_list_items.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="360dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btndel"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img"
            android:text="button 1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```